# How do I go about asking this question here on Stats.SE?

Tags: discussion

Total newb to stats: I'm an embedded programmer with a BSEE, so I like to think I've got lots of knowledge with the least possible amount of applicability to real life.

I built a test bench to observe the output of a sensor and [came up with an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269638) to quantify an anomaly I observed in the data. I wanted to know what to call it, so I asked on [Math.SE what is the average of an integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530767). While continuing to research related questions on Math.SE for a week, I just saw someone said their similar-ish question was answered on here...

Could I please get help with which tags to use to post the [Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530767) on here? Or if this is really trivial, I'd appreciate a pat on the back and *"it is $__________$, duh!"* for an answer.

Note that in the [stackoverflow alagorithm link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269638) above, I mention that standard deviation, skewness, nor Kurtosis help. Also that I have known data, so my problem isn't helped with estimation tools like linear regression.

Basically, I came up with a way to quantify the "dip" in this figure and want to know what that process is called:

[image: I caught the dip, but what is the fishing rod called?]

Comment: This question is fine for the main site. For a tag I would suggest [quality-control](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quality-control) given the nature of the objective.

Comment: There are other statistical applications that calculate statistics for areas in vaguely similar plots (e.g. GINI Coefficient, ROC curves), but it isn't obvious to me that you need to work with the area at all. Just evaluating deviations from expected may be sufficient to identify problematic sensors.

Comment: Hi, Chris. I agree with @Andy that this would be fine for the main site. It could even undergo a slight tweak to open the door to other suggestions on solutions. You've put an admirable and impressive amount of work both into the test setup and your question! If you'd like the question moved here, please *flag* it on the main math.SE site, choose "other", and ask them to migrate it to stats.SE. Cheers.

Comment: @cardinal thank you (and Andy) for the suggestion; I'll do that. Also please explain more on how to "open the door". Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisK: I've migrated your question to Cross Validated. please go ahead and edit it w.r.t. the above suggestions! http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74306/is-there-a-better-name-than-average-of-the-integral